# C++ win32 GUI code in classes

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I made a simple win32 application. I placed my GUI code in a class, but I got some bugs.

Main.cpp

```
#include "Form.h"
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Form form(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);
    form.show();
    form.set_title("Testing this stuff");
}
```

Form.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
class Form
{
private:
    HWND hwnd;
    char* title = "Form";
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
public:
    Form(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
    void set_title(const char* title);
    void show();
    ~Form();
};
```

Form.cpp

```
#include "Form.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK Form::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:

        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

Form::Form(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);// LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "test_class";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); // (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);

    if (RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "test_class", title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 300, 300, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (!hwnd == NULL)
        {
            ShowWindow(this->hwnd, SW_NORMAL);
            UpdateWindow(this->hwnd);

            MSG msg;

            while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Form::show() {
    ShowWindow(this->hwnd, SW_NORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(this->hwnd);
}

void Form::set_title(const char* title) {
    SetWindowText(this->hwnd, title);
}

Form::~Form()
{
}
```

Now, what I wanted it to do is show the window and change the title; however, the GUI doesn't show up and the set_title doesn't work either. I also tried for the set_title:

```
SendMessage(this->hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)title);
```

This doesn't work either. Also, `this->hwnd` is a variable I made in my class. I'm uncertain what's wrong and how to fix it. I want to make a similar Form system like Windows Form Application from .NET but without using any framework (only win32).

Comment: A debugger is the tool of choice. It would have told you, that your `Form::Form` c'tor never returns.

Comment: @IInspectable Um sorry but what do you mean with 'that your `Form::Form` ctor never returns'?

Comment: Ask your debugger.

Comment: `form.show();` and `form.set_title();` are called AFTER you exit the message-loop. The message-loop should have not been placed in the constructor.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker - you run message loop direct in `Form::Form` so it not return until WM_QUIT you got

Comment: Forgot to mention, I doubt if `WndProc()` can be a class member function (albeit static) and what your compler can do in this case. If your code does not work for apparently no reason, try making it a simple non-member function (you cannot access any class members from a static function anyway). And a sidenote, you don't need `this->` to access class members, eg `this->hwnd` could have been simply `hwnd`

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou: The window procedure can be a static class member (although that's a pretty useless abstraction). There is no difference between a static class member and a free function, as far as the function call goes.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I thought you had to do `this->`, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @IInspectable But in my example it isn't bad? For example, I can have multiple forms, and all have different controls. Or should I do it in a different way?

Comment: @Joshua, a typical Windows application only has _one_ message loop (`while (GetMessage`...) which services _all_ its windows. To dispatch a message to the correct object's message-handling method, you need a way to associate a GUI window with a C++ object. This is typically done either by keeping a map of window handles to window objects, or by setting the address of a window object in the "user data" of the window (see `SetWindowLong` and `GWL_USERDATA` for more info)

Comment: @JoshuaBakker: You cannot even have a single window with your code, since your constructor never returns. Writing applications is hard enough as it stands, but getting framework code right is a lot harder. Don't try to write framework code until you are intimately familiar with the underlying platform. Start here: [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't see it, of course I slapped myself to the head. And I just don't have much C++ win32 experience, tho, I have written some native console applications (no .NET).

Comment: @GavinLock: `GWLP_USERDATA` is toxic. Everyone can access it, and everyone and their dog does, too. It has turned into the most unreliably place to store window-private data (because it is essentially public). A better place would be to allocate `cbWndExtra` memory, or use [SetProp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633568.aspx) with a unique key (like a string representation of a GUID).

Comment: @IInspectable - I was always a little uncomfortable with `GWLP_USERDATA`. Thanks for better alternatives.

Comment: @IInspectable why i agree he should learn the underlying platform first, i don't agree with he shouldn't experiment with creating frameworks, when i started C++ i played around with creating my own frameworks, i failed many many times, but it got me better at doing it, moral of the story your can learn from these mistakes, but keep trying while reading up on stuff and studying, and eventually create what you want, p.s. google is a powerful tool, and try downloading a frameworks source code like SFML, and study it you can learn a lot from others code. (=

Comment: @daniel The only problem with others' code is that sometimes the code is written for experienced people so that won't help me in my learning process. I'll just start with basic GUI for now then if that's what you recommend and try to understand it better.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker my personal recommendation would be for you to use a third party GUI and windowing API until you are ready to create a full scaled API, experiment with creating your own API on the side if you need this done urgently, if you are doing all of this to just learn then just keep on with what you are doing and study a graphics API e.g. ( OpenGL, DirectX, etc ) and a underlying windowing API( Win32, WinRT, X11, Etc. ), i would also recommend you studying a bit more into C++, and the STL, hope it all works out (=

Comment: @daniel Maybe I should learn C++ first completely before starting a GUI framework - it was more for myself so I could re-use the class easy for future projects and so I could have multiple windows but I thought it was easier - guess I just thought too easy.

Comment: @daniel: WinRT is a platform, not a windowing API. The underlying windowing API of the Windows Runtime is the Windows Composition Engine (otherwise known as the Desktop Window Manager). Starting with Windows 10, it is exposed through the new [DirectComposition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437371.aspx) API.

Comment: @IInspectable i was being vague as i only had less than 100 characters left, i know WinRT is a platform not a windowing API, but knew if he typed in WinRT Windowing API on google it would hopefully pull something up pertaining to creating Window on a WinRT system like Windows 8, 8.1, or 10, but thanks for clarifying what i was saying, also thanks for the info on WinRT, am currently fresh to WinRT as i have ever only worked with the Win32, X11, and Cocoa API's so appreciated the Info (=